# Bézout coefficients of $(1-cX)^n$, $(1 - \bar c X)^n$

Tags: polynomials, partial-fractions, euclidean-algorithm

Context: I want to do partial fraction decomposition of a fraction of polynomials where the denominator is of the form $1 + aX + bX^2$.

Now to my concrete problem:
Due to Bézout's identity or, more concretely, the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, we know that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and $c\in\mathbb{C}$, there exist polynomials $p(X), q(X) \in \mathbb C[X]$ such that
$$p(X)(1 - c X)^n + q(X) (1 - \bar{c} X)^n = 1$$
Is there any simple closed form for these polynomials, perhaps in term of some well-known sequence of polynomials? Or a recursive formula for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n=1$, $p(X)$ and $q(X)$ are constant. We define $p_1 = \bar{c}/(\bar{c} - c)$ and $q_1 = -c/(\bar{c} - c)$. It can easily be seen that $p_1(1-cX)+q_1(1-\bar cX)=1$.
Then 
$$
1 = \left(p_1(1-cX)+q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{2n-1} \\
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{2n-1-k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{k} \\
=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{2n-1-k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{k} \\
+\sum\limits_{k=n}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{2n-1-k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{k}\\
=\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{n-1-k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{k} \\
+\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{n}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k+n}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{n-1-k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{k}\\
=p_1^n(1-cX)^n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{n-1-k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{k} \\
+q_1^n(1-\bar cX)^n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{n-1-k}
$$
Such that you can use
$$
p_n(X) = p_1^n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{n-1-k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{k}
$$
and
$$
q_n(X) = q_1^n\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}\left(p_1(1-cX)\right)^{k}\left(q_1(1-\bar cX)\right)^{n-1-k}
$$

Comment: Thanks for that! The derivation seems really straightforward, although I doubt I would have found it within a reasonable amount of time. Unfortunately, it seems to me at least that algorithmically, computing this is any easier or more efficient than just the Euclidean algorithm.